# How do I use row_number() to specify criteria?

Tags: t-sql

I have the following query:

```
select top 100 eid, cid, id, position, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by eid, cid, id) as record  
from standings
where record = 2
```

This gives an invalid column error.

How can I only retrieve a specific record number.  I need to do this to iterate through results one at a time for data conversion with a table that has no identity primary key (or primary key in general)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Row_Number() function in Where Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pull if from a CTE

```
;with T as (
   select top 100 eid, cid, id, position, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by eid, cid, id) as record  
   from standings
)
select * from T where record = 2
```

Comment: If the CTE is not the 1st statement in a batch the `;` is mandatory, if it is you don't need it, but as adding one is still fine, I always do.