# Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone explain why can't we use windowed functions in `group by` clause and why it's allowed only in `SELECT` and `ORDER BY`

I was trying to group the records based on `row_number()` and a column in SQL Server as like this:

```
SELECT Invoice
from table1
group by row_number() over(order by Invoice),Invoice
```

I am getting an error

> *Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY*

I can select this `row_number()` in SELECT clause but I want to know why can't we use it group by?

Comment: What's the point of grouping by a `row_number()`? Each item will be in a group by itself. The question is quite legitimate, though.

Comment: the things is consider if I have duplicate Invoice, In such case I would like to keep that also. U can think then why should I group. the thing is I want to why it's like that? Why cant we use windowed functions in group by?

Comment: how it will create ambiguity. Can you explain? In case I just want to select rank value 2 in where clause. Hw it will create ambiguity

Comment: So you want to use it in the where clause not group by then?

Comment: No no. I just gave an example. Want to use it group by as well..

Comment: Windowed functions are defined in the ANSI spec to logically execute after the processing of `GROUP BY, HAVING, WHERE`, I guess they could have defined it another way and allowed the `GROUP BY` to use a window function operating on a different window from that used by the `SELECT` but that would surely be quite confusing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Windowed functions are defined in the ANSI spec to logically execute after the processing of `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `WHERE`.

To be more specific they are allowed at steps 5.1 and 6 in the [Logical Query Processing flow chart here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140325065934/http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf) .

I suppose they could have defined it another way and allowed `GROUP BY`, `WHERE`, `HAVING` to use window functions with the window being the logical result set at the start of that phase but suppose they had and we were allowed to construct queries such as

```
SELECT a, 
       b, 
       NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS NtileForSelect
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) > 1
  GROUP BY a, 
           b, 
           NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b)
  HAVING NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) = 1
```

With four different logical windows in play good luck working out what the result of this would be! Also what if in the `HAVING` you actually wanted to filter by the expression from the `GROUP BY` level above rather than with the window of rows being the result after the `GROUP BY`?

The CTE version is more verbose but also more explicit and easier to follow.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT a, 
       b, 
       NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS NtileForWhere
  FROM YourTable
), T2 AS
(
SELECT a,
       b,
       NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS NtileForGroupBy
FROM T1
WHERE NtileForWhere > 1
), T3 AS
(
SELECT a,
       b,
       NtileForGroupBy,
       NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS NtileForHaving
FROM T2
GROUP BY a,b, NtileForGroupBy
)
SELECT a,
       b,
       NTILE(2) OVER (PARTITION BY a ORDER BY b) AS NtileForSelect
FROM T3
WHERE NtileForHaving = 1
```

As these are all defined in the `SELECT` statement and are aliased it is easily achievable to disambiguate results from different levels e.g. simply by switching `WHERE NtileForHaving = 1` to `NtileForGroupBy = 1`

Comment: Logical Query Processing flow chart was very informative. thanks @Martin and your explanation speaks a lot and makes sense :)

Comment: now the Logical Query Processing flow chart..LINK is broken

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName If you search for `"Logical Query Processing Poster" filetype:pdf` it looks like a few people made copies.

Comment: found it at https://abhijitmore.files.wordpress.com/2010/03/logical-query-processing.pdf
Interestingly the Top appears in the diagram to be done before the order by.  Just weird.

Comment: @Alex - I think that was just an error. This site lists a newer ordering by the same author (Itzik Ben Gan) that corrects this. http://porterwebsites.com/sql-server-logical-query/

Answer (score 20):

You can work around that by placing the window function in a subquery:

```
select  invoice
,       rn
from    (
        select  Invoice
        ,       row_number() over(order by Invoice) as rn
        from    Table1
        ) as SubQueryAlias
group by
        invoice
,       rn
```

Comment: Yeah bro. I know that and my concern is why cant we use it within a query? Why it's designed in that way?

Comment: Well, SQL Server can't even parse simple aliases in the `where` clause.  For example, this won't work: `select datediff(day,col1,col2) as ddiff from YourTable where ddiff > 1`.  I assume it's some kind of limitation of their parser.

Comment: hmm I never knew that. Thanks for your clarification on this:)

Comment: Shouldn't the 'rn' be in the outer select as well?

Comment: And shouldnt invoice be either added to the group by or removed from the select or aggregated?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yeah, I'm assuming that's not the point of the question though.

Comment: @Andomar: it's not a parser problem, it has to do with the order of operations. The fields in the SELECT list are generated after the rows have been selected (filtered) by the WHERE clause. You can't use data you haven't yet calculated.

Comment: This isn't a limitation of SQL Server; the SQL Standard says that column aliases can't be used in a WHERE clause.