# SQL to LEFT JOIN with COUNT()

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I' working on SQL but having an issue with the error below:

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Error occurs because I have `COUNT()`  in my code. I know this is a nasty code but kinda works...

So it tries to join the `tblAmpReport` table by `tblAmpReport.WEB_ID` with `WEB_ID`. `WEB_IB` is calculated with this nasty code below. However, `COUNT()` seems to be causing an issue. Does anyone know a better way of overcoming this?

```
left join tblAmplianceReport
    on ISNULL(tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID,
                case
                when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 1
                    then case
                        when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+cast(tblCrystalBeauty.RETAIL_PRICE as varchar(10))) = count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT)
                            then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                        else case
                                when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 4
                                    then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                end
                        end
                else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                end) = tblAmplianceReport.WEB_ID
```

FULL SQL:

```
select tblCrystalBeauty.GROUP_NO
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.GROUP_NAME
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.DEPT_NAME
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.CLASS_NAME
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.BRAND
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.MAIN_SEASON
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.SUB_SEASON
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.SUB_NAME
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.PRODUCT_TYPE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.PL_CYCLE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM as ITEM
      ,cast(tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM as int) as ITEM_VALUE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_DESC
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT as ITEM_PARENT
      ,cast(tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT as int) as ITEM_PARENT_VALUE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.VPN
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.SUPP_COLOUR
      ,tblCrystalBeauty._COLOUR
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.SIZE_1
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.SIZE_2
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.RETAIL_PRICE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.EAN as EAN
      ,cast(tblCrystalBeauty.EAN as bigint) as EAN_VALUE
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.WH_SOH
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND
      ,tblCrystalBeauty.CREATE_DATETIME
      ,ISNULL(tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID,
                             case
                               when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 1
                                 then case
                                        when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+cast(tblCrystalBeauty.RETAIL_PRICE as varchar(10))) = count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT)
                                          then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                        else case
                                               when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 4
                                                 then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                               else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                             end
                                      end
                               else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                             end) as "WEB_ID"
      ,case
         when row_number() over(partition by ISNULL(ISNULL(tblODIPublished.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID),tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) order by
              (
                                                                                                                                                                      select 1
              )) > 1
           then 0
         else 1
       end as OPTION_COUNT
      ,case
         when sum(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 0
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as IN_STOCK
      ,sum(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) as STYLE_SOH
      ,case
         when case
                when tblCrystalBeauty.PL_CYCLE = 'Discontinued'
                     or tblCrystalBeauty.PL_CYCLE = 'Discontinued'
                  then 'NO'
                else 'YES'
              end = 'YES'
              and case
                    when charindex('Dum',tblCrystalBeauty.CLASS_NAME) > 0
                      then 'NO'
                    else 'YES'
                  end = 'YES'
              and tblBrands.WEB_ALLOWED = 'Yes'
           then 1
         else 0
       end as CONGRUENCY
      ,ISNULL(tblBrands.CUTOUTS,'DN') as USE_COUTOUTS
      ,'' as MARKED_FOR_WEB_WEB_ID
      ,case
         when tblMarkedForWeb.CREATE_DATETIME is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as MARKED_FOR_WEB_SKU
      ,cast(tblMarkedForWeb.CREATE_DATETIME as datetime) as MFWD
      ,case
         when tblODIPublished.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as PUBLISHED
      ,cast(tblODIPublished.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE as datetime) as PD
      ,case
         when tblODIPublished.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE is not null
           then 1
         else 0
       end as PUBLISHED_COUNT
      ,case
         when case
                when tblBeautyCopy.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE is not null
                  then 'YES'
                else 'NO'
              end = 'YES'
              and case
                    when tblAmplianceReport.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED is not null
                      then 'YES'
                    else 'NO'
                  end = 'YES'
              and case
                    when tblODIPublished.SKU_B4N_UPLOAD_MODIFIED_DATE is not null
                      then 'YES'
                    else 'NO'
                  end = 'NO'
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as READY_TO_UPLOAD
      ,case
         when tblAmplianceReport.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as IMG_UPLOADED
      ,tblAmplianceReport.IMAGE_DATE_UPLOADED as IUD
      ,tblBeautyCopy.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE
      ,case
         when tblBeautyCopy.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as COPY_COMP
      ,tblBeautyCopy.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE as CACD
      ,case
         when tblBeautyCopy.COPY_COMPLETE_DATE is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as CAT_COMP
      ,case
         when tblTransfers.CREATE_DATE is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as TRANSFERRED_TO_PACKSHOT
      ,tblTransfers.CREATE_DATE as TTPD
      ,case
         when tblImageOrder.DATE is not null
           then 'YES'
         else 'NO'
       end as IMAGE_ORDER
      ,tblImageOrder.DATE as IOD
      ,MV_REP_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL.ONLINE_FLAG as DW_ONLINE_FLAG_WCID
      ,MV_REP_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL.PUBLISHED as DW_PUBLISHED_FLAG_WCID
      ,MV_REP_PUBLISHED_SKU_LEVEL.ONLINE_FLAG as DW_ONLINE_FLAG_SKU
      ,MV_REP_PUBLISHED_SKU_LEVEL.PUBLISHED as DW_PUBLISHED_FLAG_SKU
      ,ISNULL(tblDepartment.DEPARTMENT,'DN') as DEPARTMENT
from tblCrystalBeauty
    left join tblODIPublished
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM = tblODIPublished.SKU
    left join tblWebIDLegacy
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM = tblWebIDLegacy.SkuId
    left join tblAmplianceReport
        on ISNULL(tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID,
                                 case
                                   when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 1
                                     then case
                                            when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+cast(tblCrystalBeauty.RETAIL_PRICE as varchar(10))) = count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT)
                                              then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                            else case
                                                   when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 4
                                                     then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                                   else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                                 end
                                          end
                                   else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                 end) = tblAmplianceReport.WEB_ID
    left join tblBeautyCopy
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT = tblBeautyCopy.RETEK_PARENT
    left join tblMarkedForWeb
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM = tblMarkedForWeb.ITEM
    left join tblImageOrder
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT = tblImageOrder.ITEM_PARENT
    left join tblBrands
        on cast(tblCrystalBeauty.GROUP_NO as varchar(10))+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.BRAND = tblBrands.PRIMARY_KEY
    left join MV_REP_PUBLISHED_SKU_LEVEL
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM = MV_REP_PUBLISHED_SKU_LEVEL.SKU
    left join MV_REP_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL
        on ISNULL(ISNULL(tblODIPublished.WEB_PROD_STYLE_ID,tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID),
                                                                                           case
                                                                                             when charindex('Oxfo',tblCrystalBeauty.SIZE_1) = 1
                                                                                               then cast(tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT as varchar(10))+'OX'
                                                                                             else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                                                                           end) = MV_REP_PUBLISHED_WCID_LEVEL.PRODUCT_ID
    left join tblTransfers
        on tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM = tblTransfers.ITEM
    left join tblDepartment
        on cast(tblCrystalBeauty.GROUP_NO as varchar(10))+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.GROUP_NAME = tblDepartment.GROUP_NAME
where tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT is not null
      and tblCrystalBeauty.PL_CYCLE != 'Discontinued'
order by WEB_ID desc;
```

Comment: Please include your entire formatted query, along with sample input and output.

Comment: What does `mysql` have to do with `sql-server` ?

Comment: HI @TimBiegeleisen , this is a massive query to return 54 columns from 10 tables. Code is below:

Comment: @B001 sorry, it was a typo... removed the mysql tag. Apologies again

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a good start before asking queries like this.

Comment: Seems to me the problem is not the COUNT so much as the OVER following the count.  That is the window function here.  You might want to try separating out into a subquery or even a CTE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111321/windowed-functions-can-only-appear-in-the-select-or-order-by-clauses)

Comment: You're using a Window Function in the `FROM` as part of your joins.  You can only use a Window Function in `SELECT` or `Order BY` as the error indicates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this by using the APPLY operator. Here you can refer your other tables and simply move your "join on" part to the where clause.

In your case it should look something like:

```
cross apply (


        select ISNULL(tblWebIDLegacy.WebProductStyleID,
                                 case
                                   when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 1
                                     then case
                                            when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+cast(tblCrystalBeauty.RETAIL_PRICE as varchar(10))) = count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT)
                                              then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                            else case
                                                   when count(tblCrystalBeauty.STOCK_ON_HAND) over(partition by tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT) > 4
                                                     then tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT+'_'+tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM
                                                   else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                                 end
                                          end
                                   else tblCrystalBeauty.ITEM_PARENT
                                 end) as joincolumn
                                 --Add columns you need at the main select
                                 from tblAmplianceReport)

                                 -- add this to your where clause at the end
                                 where joincolumn = tblAmplianceReport.WEB_ID
```