# SQL ERROR - Windows functions can only appear in SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl, calculated-columns, window-functions

I am relatively new to SQL and am trying to sort out why I am getting the error in the post title. (I think it has something to do with the LAG function?)

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
ADD Calc_Column AS CAST
(
    CASE WHEN [Variable_X]  = LAG([Variable_X],1,0) OVER (Order By FileDate)
          AND [Variable_Y] != LAG([Variable_Y],1,0) OVER (Order By FileDate) 
          AND [ACTUAL START DATE] != 0
          AND [FileDate] >= [ACTUAL START DATE]
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS N
)
GO
```

Comment: Which part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: pls give us a sample data and expected result. Thanks.

Comment: It's says in the error that window functions can only be used in `SELECT` or `ORDER BY`, so it can't be used in the `CASE` statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111321/windowed-functions-can-only-appear-in-the-select-or-order-by-clauses

Comment: Thank you for your responses everyone. Remus and Valerica- I am unsure which part is the windows function. (Is that the LAG?) If so, how would I get it outside the case, when I need it for the formula comparison?

Comment: @mitchmitch24 . . . You can use a view for this functionality.

Comment: Hey Gordon thanks for your response! A view would be the LAG statement essentially captured as an alias and then referred to in my CASE? I want to make sure I understand.

Comment: Anything with an OVER is a Window function.

Comment: First make it work as a select then package the select in a view

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear: You can use window functions (`lag`), in this case, anywhere other then the `select` clause or the `order by` clause.
A computed column can only refer to values from functions or from it's current row, it can't have select statements directly in it's declaration.
But it can be computed using a user defined scalar function, So if you really want to computed column that is computed using window functions, you have to do it using a user defined function. I've tried to make a sample function for you, but since you didn't share your table's DDL I had to make assumptions and guesses, and I couldn't test it - so it might not fit exactly. However, it should be enough to show the general idea, and you should be able to modify it to your needs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalculateMyColumn
(
    -- Assuming an int identity column with ascending order
    @PrimaryKeyColumn int 
)
Returns Bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue bit

    ;WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT Variable_X, 
               LAG([Variable_X],1,0) OVER (Order By FileDate) As Prev_Variable_X,
               Variable_Y, 
               LAG([Variable_Y],1,0) OVER (Order By FileDate) As Prev_Variable_Y,
               [ACTUAL START DATE], 
               [FileDate],
               PrimaryKeyColumn
        FROM TableName
        WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn <= @PrimaryKeyColumn
    )

    SELECT @ReturnValue = 
            CASE WHEN Variable_X = Prev_Variable_X
                 AND Variable_Y != Prev_Variable_Y
                 AND [ACTUAL START DATE] != 0
                 AND [FileDate] >= [ACTUAL START DATE]
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END
    FROM cte
    WHERE PrimaryKeyColumn = @PrimaryKeyColumn

END
```

Then you can alter your table to add the calculated column:

```
ALTER TABLE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
ADD Calc_Column AS dbo.CalculateMyColumn(PrimaryKeyColumn)
GO
```

**Please note** that this function relies on the primary key column being an int identity column with ascending order.

Comment: Well done - this was what I was going to suggest but with an important caveat: T-SQL scalar UDFs for computed columns, check constraints or anything for that matter, are performance killers. Their very presence causes the optimizer to choose a serial execution plan even when a parallel plan is better. Note this great article by Eric Darling: Another reason why scalar functions in computed columns is a bad idea (https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/01/another-reason-why-scalar-functions-in-computed-columns-is-a-bad-idea/).

Comment: @AlanBurstein Thanks for the link! I know that scalar UDFs usually means bad performance, but I don't know of any other way to have a computed column depend on anything outside of built-in functions and current row data.  Perhaps Gordon's suggestion to make a view is a better solution.