# Apply eloquent eager limit query using SQL ROW_NUMBER in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading, laravel-query-builder

As @JonasStaudenmeir answered on [laravel eager loading with limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607088/laravel-eager-loading-with-limit#52991461), which query looks like:

```
User::select('id')
    ->with([
        'posts' => fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])->limit(4)
    ])
    ->limit(2)
->get();
```

[image]

```
select `id` from `users` limit 2

select * from (select `id`, `user_id`, row_number() over (partition by `posts`.`user_id`) as laravel_row from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 3)) as laravel_table where laravel_row <= 4 order by laravel_row
```

Now, my interest is to do it manually which is what I tried here:

```
User::select('id')
->with([
    'posts' => fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])
        ->selectRaw("row_number() over (partition by `posts`.`user_id`) as laravel_row")
        ->where('laravel_row', '<=', 4)
        ->orderBy('laravel_row')
])
->limit(2)
->get();
```

Also, I take some help from online ([SQLtoEloquent](https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/)), but the syntax was not properly formed so it failed there too.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'laravel_row' in 'where clause'

select `id`, `user_id`, row_number() over (partition by `posts`.`user_id`) as laravel_row from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 3) and `laravel_row` <= 4 order by `laravel_row` asc
```

**UPDATE:**

Following @Igor's advice, I tried to make it similar to the package and more convenient but didn't match the expected output.

*App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php*

```
public function boot(): void
{
    \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation::macro('limit', function(int $value) {

        if($this->parent->exists) {

           $this->query->limit($value);

        } elseif ($value >= 0) {

            // When I tried on the Model(User), it succeeded the below logic
            // 2 was expected because the total number of users fetched is 2 but it didn't happen
            $parentLimitValue = $this->query->getQuery()->limit; // null

            // $parentLimitValue = $this->parent->getQuery()->limit; // null
            // $parentLimitValue = $this->related->getQuery()->limit; // null

            $parentLimitValue ??= 1;

            $this->query
                ->selectRaw("row_number() over (partition by ".$this->getExistenceCompareKey().") as laravel_row")
                ->orderBy('laravel_row')
            ->limit($value * ($parentLimitValue ?: 1));
        }
        return $this;
    });
}
```

**Does anyone know where I should put my eyes to minimize this package?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to remove **where** and add **limit** into the subquery

```
User::select('id')
->with([
    'posts' => fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])
        ->selectRaw("row_number() over (partition by `posts`.`user_id`) as laravel_row")
        ->orderBy('laravel_row')
        ->limit(4) 
])
->limit(2)
->get();
```

**UPDATE**

To limit users and posts per users use this:

```
$usersCount = 2;
$postsPerUser = 4;
$users = User::select('id')
->with([
    'posts' => fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])
        ->selectRaw("row_number() over (partition by `posts`.`user_id`) as laravel_row")
        ->limit($usersCount * $postsPerUser) 
        ->orderBy('laravel_row')
])
->limit($usersCount)
->get();
```

Comment: Yeah! But the question is how the data be arranged/taken. Instead of getting 4 posts for each user, it will get 2-2 posts for each user. So, it's not what I expected.

Comment: Try with ... **->groupBy('user_id')->limit(4)** ... into the subquery?

Comment: OK then, seems like is better to create **latestPost** hasOne relation and do it like that. **Partition by**  is not seems appropriate for your case.

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780740/3955714](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33780740/3955714)

Comment: One possible solution is that we can trick your answer in such ways that it will multiply both limit values i.e. `limit(4x2)`. By doing this, it will match my expected output but it goes query like `limit(8)` at the end in SQL.

Comment: Also, your groupBy method throws me this error. [Window function is allowed only in SELECT list and ORDER BY clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111321/windowed-functions-can-only-appear-in-the-select-or-order-by-clauses). If you can answer, please let know?

Answer (score 0):

As per @Igor's response, I made it more handy by placing it in [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) & [local scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#local-scopes).

*App\Traits\WithEagerLimit.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

trait WithEagerLimit
{
    public function scopeWithEagerLimit(Builder $builder, string $relation, callable $callback)
    {
        return $builder->with([ $relation => function($query) use ($builder, $callback) {

            $limit = $builder->getQuery()->limit ?: 1;

            // Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
            $query = call_user_func_array($callback, [$query]);

            // Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
            $dbQB = $query->getQuery()->getQuery();

            if(!$dbQB->limit) {
                return $query;
            }

            $dbQB->limit *=  $limit;

            return $query->when(is_null($dbQB->columns), fn($q) => $q->select('*'))
                ->selectRaw("row_number() over (partition by ".$query->getExistenceCompareKey().") as laravel_row")
                ->orderBy('laravel_row');
        }]);
    }
}
```

Use the `WithEagerLimit` trait on the corresponding model.

*For example:*

```
class User extends Model {

    use \App\Traits\WithEagerLimit;
    
    //...

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Now, you can chain `withEagerLimit()` to any of your queries by doing the following:

**Simple eager loading functionality**

```
User::withEagerLimit('posts', fn($query) => $query)->get();

// SQL
select * from `users`

select * from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

**Conditions on eager loading functionality**

```
User::query()
    ->withEagerLimit('posts', fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])->where('id', '<=', 5))
->get();

// SQL
select * from `users`

select `id`, `user_id` from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) and `id` <= 5
```

**Complex SQL RAW query on eager loading functionality**

```
User::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->withEagerLimit('posts',
        fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])
            ->whereRaw('MOD(id, 2) = 0')
            ->limit(4)
    )
    ->whereRaw('MOD(id, 2) = 1')
    ->skip(3)
    ->take(2)
    ->latest('id')
->get();

// SQL
select `id` from `users` where MOD(id, 2) = 1 order by `id` desc limit 2 offset 3

select `id`, `user_id`, row_number() over (partition by posts.user_id) as laravel_row from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 3) and MOD(id, 2) = 0 order by `laravel_row` asc limit 8
```

**Pagination on eager loading functionality**

```
User::query()
    ->withEagerLimit('posts', fn($query) => $query->limit(4))
->paginate(5);

// SQL
select count(*) as aggregate from `users`

select * from `users` limit 5 offset 0

select *, row_number() over (partition by posts.user_id) as laravel_row from `posts` where `posts`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) order by `laravel_row` asc limit 20
```

**For those eagerly waiting for an answer**

You should call `->limit($value)` or an equivalent method (i.e. `take()`, `skip()`, `paginate()`, or similar procedure) in any queries chained with `->withEagerLimit($relationName, $callback)` in the main-query and also in sub-query.

```
User::query()
    ->select('id')
    ->withEagerLimit('posts', fn($query) => $query->select(['id', 'user_id'])->limit(4))
    ->limit(2)
->get();
```

You get the benefits of using this trait only when the query meets enough results on both the tables i.e. *users* & *posts*. Otherwise, you will get extra results out of the box because here we have done `UsersLimit x PostsLimit`, so keep the query accordingly.