# Analytic Functions SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I ask to help with a question on analytical/aggregate queries.
There is a table of changes in the value of val.
The value may change, I may not.
I am calculating the number of the day when the value was last changed.
(in the example it is 5).

```
with part_table as(
select src_table.* 
, lag(val) over (partition by id order by nday) prev_val
, lead(val) over (partition by id order by nday) nex_val
from 
  (
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 1 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value2' val, 2 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 3 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value2' val, 4 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 5 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 6 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 7 nday from dual 
  ) src_table
) select 
  t.* 
  ,(select max(nday) from part_table t2 where t2.id=t.id and t2.val <> t2.prev_val) max_nday
from part_table t
order by id, nday
```

I have a question, I don't understand how to do it without a subquery, in a window...
After all, it is impossible to pass a condition to aggregate functions, right?

```
with part_table as(
select src_table.* 
, lag(val) over (partition by id order by nday) prev_val
, lead(val) over (partition by id order by nday) nex_val
, max(nday) over (partition by id order by nday) max_nday --- how to get 5?
from 
  (
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 1 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value2' val, 2 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 3 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value2' val, 4 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 5 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 6 nday from dual union all
  select 1 id, 'value1' val, 7 nday from dual 
  ) src_table
) select 
  t.* 
from part_table t
order by id, nday
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a windowed function as a clause

[Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111321/windowed-functions-can-only-appear-in-the-select-or-order-by-clauses)

And the `LAG()` function appears to be most suitable for your problem. It makes it necessary to use subquerying.

My easier solution outputs last day the change happened for every `id` in a provided table and includes the case a value has never changed:

```
BEGIN TRAN

-- provided data
CREATE TABLE dual (id INT, val VARCHAR(10), nday INT IDENTITY(1,1));

INSERT INTO dual VALUES
    (2, 'value1'),(2, 'value1'),(1, 'value1'),(1, 'value1'),(1, 'value1'),(1, 'value2'),(1, 'value1');

-- solution
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        id, val, nday,
        LAG(val) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY nday) AS prev
    FROM dual)
SELECT
    id,
    COALESCE(MAX(nday), 1) AS last_day_of_change
FROM cte 
WHERE val <> prev OR prev IS NULL
GROUP BY id

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description your sql seems unnecessarily complicated. I think you could solve this simply without all the unions:

```
create table #src_table (
    id int, 
    nday int, 
    [value] int, 
    primary key (id))
insert into #src_table values 
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 2),
    (3, 3, 3),
    (4, 4, 3),
    (5, 5, 4), -- last day with a change
    (6, 6, 4),
    (7, 7, 4)


;with cte as (
    select
        nday,
        isnull([value] - lag([value]) over (order by id), 0) as IsChanged
    from #src_table 
    ) 
select max(nday) 
from cte
where cte.IsChanged = 1
```

Result here is `5` - the last day with a change.