# convert a subquery to over

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

You can convert this query for example to optimize over for a consultation, is to get you up depending on the version, it's the same table.

```
select MAX(y.Version),
 y.Unidad,
 y.RutCompañia,
 y.Cobertura,
 y.Temporada,
 y.PorcentajeSubsidio,y.RendimientoInferior,y.RendimientoSuperior 
from ddbb.dbo.NS_CA y 
where y.IDVariedad='010101' and y.Temporada ='2011'
and y.ZHS='CA0607'
and y.Moneda='UF'
and y.Version in (select MAX(x.Version) from ddbb.dbo.NS_CA  x where x.IDVariedad='010101' and x.Temporada ='2011'
and x.ZHS='CA0607'
and x.Moneda='UF')
group by y.Unidad,y.RutCompañia,y.Cobertura,y.Temporada,y.PorcentajeSubsidio,y.RendimientoInferior,y.RendimientoSuperior
```

I imagined something like this

```
select  MAX(b.Version) OVER(PARTITION BY b.IDVariedad,b.IDRubro ) as maximo
```

but it does not work properly

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for you translate and answers.
Add more info , by example i have next table (tabla) :

```
| Version    | Temporada   | Unidad       | etc          |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 00         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
| 00         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
| 01         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
| 02         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
| 03         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
| 03         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
```

and query i would generate is :

```
select * from tabla a
where a.version in (select max(b.Version) from tabla b where b.Temporada='2011')


    | Version    | Temporada   | Unidad       | etc          |
    | 03         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
    | 03         |        2011 |    N         |  xx          |
```

is possibility change  sub-query to 'over partition'  ?  , thanks

Comment: Please translate your question to English. If the language you're speaking is Portuguese, check out http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I moved the SQL SERVER 2012 from the title to the tags. But it does not look like SQL server to me, please adjust correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte as
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by y.Version DESC) row_id
    ,   y.Unidad
    ,   y.RutCompañia
    ,   y.Cobertura
    ,   y.Temporada
    ,   y.PorcentajeSubsidio
    ,   y.RendimientoInferior
    ,   y.RendimientoSuperior
FROM ddbb.dbo.NS_CA y
WHERE y.IDVariedad = '010101'
    AND y.Temporada = '2011'
    AND y.ZHS = 'CA0607'
    AND y.Moneda = 'UF'
    AND y.Version)


SELECT * FROM cte
where row_id = 1
```

Comment: ,apparently did not express properly what I'm looking for is to extract the maxima 'Version' of a specific year and other combinations, thanks.

Comment: Use the select query with row_id =1. That should give you the max version without the use of the sub query

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want this:

```
select MAX(y.Version),
 y.Unidad,
 y.RutCompañia,
 y.Cobertura,
 y.Temporada,
 y.PorcentajeSubsidio,y.RendimientoInferior,y.RendimientoSuperior 
from y.Version =
     (select MAX(x.Version) 
        from ddbb.dbo.NS_CA  x 
       where x.IDVariedad=y.IDVariedad and x.Temporada = y.Temporada
             and x.ZHS=y.ZHS   and x.Moneda=y.Moneda)
group by y.Unidad,y.RutCompañia,y.Cobertura,y.Temporada,y.PorcentajeSubsidio,y.RendimientoInferior,y.RendimientoSuperior
```

See [Why no windowed functions in where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997396/3630826)