# Filter rows based on window function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently, I saw a user, who was the only one being awarded some badge.

Curiously, I headed over to [data.se](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow) and looked for similar examples with ([data.se - Single awarded badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/561566/single-awarded-badges))

```
select count(*) as awarded,
       name, class
from badges
group by name, class
having count(*) = 1
```

---

Taking this further, I also wanted to see the users, who were owning these badges ([data.se - Count awarded badges and users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/561583/count-awarded-badges-and-users))

```
select count(*) over (partition by b.name, b.class) as awarded,
       b.name, b.class, u.displayname
from badges b
join users u on u.id = b.userid
```

This gives me all entries, not only the single owning ones, e.g. `count(*) = 1`. To get only these, I must use a CTE or subquery, e.g. ([data.se - Single awarded badges and users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/561557/single-awarded-badges-and-users))

```
with q as (select count(*) over (partition by b.name, b.class) as awarded,
                  b.name, b.class, u.displayname
           from badges b
           join users u on u.id = b.userid)
select name, class, displayname
from q
where awarded = 1
```

The drawback of these last two queries is performance. The (non-cached) query takes about 20 times of the simple `group by/having` query. Using a subquery gives no improvement.

---

I am aware, that you can't use the [window function in a where or having clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13997177/1741542), nor say `where awarded = 1` in the second query.

Are there faster and simpler queries, maybe even without a CTE or subquery? I give one (with CTE) as my own answer, but would like to see alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to take the `group by/having` query as a CTE and join with the badges and users tables ([data.se - Single awarded badges and users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/562520/single-awarded-badges-and-users))

```
with awarded as (select count(*) as num,
                        name, class
                 from badges
                 group by name, class
                 having count(*) = 1)
select b.name, b.class, u.displayname
from badges b
join awarded a on a.name = b.name and a.class = b.class
join users u on u.id = b.userid
```