# Qualify equivalent clause in BigQuery Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any equivalent 'Qualify' clause of Teradata in BigQuery Standard SQ?

I need it because we cant use analytic functions in Where/Having clause.

Comment: What about pushing your analytic function down to a sub/nested select and filtering on top of it?

Comment: Yes I can do that but I am expecting some kind of a one line solution like the way it happens in Teradata

Comment: I don't believe it exists. I could be wrong, but I don't see anything in the docs.

Comment: you can submit feature request for this!

Comment: `QUALIFY` appears to be a Teradata-specific extension to the SQL standard that isn't implemented by any other SQL engines.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard Good to know that Snowflake supports it too :) - [Why no windowed functions in where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997177/why-no-windowed-functions-in-where-clauses)

Comment: QUALIFY is now suported by BQ. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has since been released (was pre-GA at the time of writing, now GA as pointed out by Ran below):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause

Comment: ... and now in GA!

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent query is:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (_row_number)
FROM  (SELECT {{ COLUMNS }}
              , ROW_NUMBER() {{ RULE }} AS _row_number
       FROM   {{ MY_TABLE }}) AS t
WHERE  _row_number = 1
```