# Expression "neither grouped nor aggregated" in BigQuery, how to include it without having to group by it?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this block of code:

```
(SELECT SELL_STR.SELL_STR_NBR, DATES.PSTD_FSCL_YR_WK, count(*) as WKLY_DLVRY--, WORK_ORD_NBR
from `analytics-df-thd.DFS.FACTS_DLY_DELV_STATS` A
inner join R1
on r1.FSCL_YR_WK = A.DATES.PSTD_FSCL_YR_WK
group by SELL_STR.SELL_STR_NBR, DATES.PSTD_FSCL_YR_WK
)
```

I need to add WORK_ORD_NBR to the SELECT so I can later join it

```
select 
WKLY_DLVRY.WKLY_DLVRY
...
from table1 a
join
WKLY_DLVRY
on WKLY_DLVRY.WORK_ORD_NBR = a.WORK_ORD_NBR
```

However when added to WKLY_DLVRY, I receive this error:

```
SELECT list expression references column WORK_ORD_NBR which is neither grouped nor aggregated at
```

I have read many threads and they didn't give me many options, only suggesting that WORK_ORD_NBR must be grouped, however that changes the count. I appreciate any help

Comment: This looks like a good suggestion ... https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/103533

Seems that you need to add your column into your "group by"

Comment: I cannot do that though, it would change my count(*)

Comment: If you don't get an answer, post to the question a trivial substitute question using some sample data (a CSV) and a simple query that is logically equivalent but removes all the project specific complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a column without grouping like below.

For more information please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68125992/bigquery-group-by-vs-partition-by-when-appending-the-auxiliary-columns).

```
SELECT
    count(*) as WKLY_DLVRY,
    ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(WORK_ORD_NBR)
        -- ORDER BY [column] DESC LIMIT 1  -- if you want to distinguish multiple values
    )[OFFSET(0)].*,
FROM ~
```