# ROW_NUMBER query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql

```
--1
(select * , row_number() over (order by columnname) as tempcolumn 
 from tablename )

--2
select * , row_number() over (order by defid) as tempcolumn 
from fields 
where tempcolumn between 1 and 2
```

The first query will give the entire table with a new column added.

I need to display the result after checking the range of the tempcolumn.
 The second query which i tried throws an error like tempcolumn doesnot exist

Answer (score 2):

You could use subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY columnname) as tempcolumn 
  from  tablename) sub
WHERE tempcolumn <= 2;
```

You cannot use alias from `SELECT` in `WHERE` clause at the same level and you cannot use `ROW_NUMBER()` as part of `WHERE`.

More info:

- [PostgreSQL: using a calculated column in the same query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840228/postgresql-using-a-calculated-column-in-the-same-query)
- [Why no windowed functions in where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997177/why-no-windowed-functions-in-where-clauses)