# Can LAG be used with HAVING?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, lag, having

I distinctly recall that T-SQL will never let you mix `LAG` and `WHERE`. For example,

```
SELECT FOO
WHERE LAG(BAR) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) > 7
```

will never work. T-SQL will not run it no matter what you do. But does T-SQL ever let you mix `LAG` with `HAVING`?

Note: All that an answer needs to do is either give a theory-based or documentation-based reason why it does not, or give any example at all of where it does.

Comment: No, you need to use CTE or subquery to make it then `where` to filter

Comment: [Why no windowed functions in where clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33522288/5070879). WHERE - filter on row level, HAVING - filter on result of aggregation, QUALIFY* - filter on windowed fucntion level. QUALIFY is  SQL language extension not supported by SQL Server

Comment: LAG is a window function. And window functions are processed after the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but before the `ORDER BY`. So you can sort by a window function. In TeraData & Snowflake there's [QUALIFY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/qualify.html). But in MS Sql Server you typically wrap it in a sub-query and filter outside the sub-query.

Comment: Tell me, do you class this as "mixing lag and where": `SELECT * FROM (SELECT LAG(x) OVER(ORDER BY y) xlag FROM z) a WHERE xlag = 1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement):

> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
> order, for a SELECT statement......
>
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Window functions are evaluated at the level of `SELECT`, which comes after `HAVING`, so the answer is *no* you can't use window functions in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I've always thought that list from the documentation was weird, it doesn't actually contain Window Functions, nor does it contain `APPLY` or `PIVOT` or `UNPIVOT` or `FOR XML/JSON`, and what is `ON` as opposed to `JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

`Having` clause can only be used with `Group by` clause. In order to use `Group by` the listed columns should be aggregated using `Group by` columns. `Group by` can only be used with aggregate functions like `min,max,sum,count` functions. Hence it is not possible to combine `having` clause along with the `LAG` analytical function.

In order to use `LAG` and `Having`, one should use CTE or subquery.

Comment: Not exactly true; I'm aware of at least two databases out there that permit HAVING without GROUP BY

Comment: @CaiusJard In that case, `HAVING` implies a `GROUP BY ()` or grouping by the empty set, which is not quite the same as using aggregates without either `HAVING` or `GROUP BY` (scalar vs vector aggregates)