# How To Delete Particular Row From MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with only one column, how could I delete a particular row from it? I know the most logical answer would be to have another column in the table with a number that automatically increments, but in a table with only one column, how would I go about doing this? Is there something I can add in the WHERE clause to say row = 3 or something similar?

Comment: No.   You can only delete a row based on the values in the row.

Comment: Does this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause

Comment: What you can do is create another column, fill it with sequencial data, index it (not really needed, but it will be better) then delete based on this new row.

Comment: Is the target value unique or are you willing to delete *all* rows with that value?

Comment: It's unique, only the one row should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
delete t from t
   where col = @value;
```

However, that will delete *all* rows with the value.  If the value is unique, you should declare the column to be either unique or a primary key.

I should add that you can delete just one row with the value by adding `limit 1`:

```
delete t from t
   where col = @value
   limit 1;
```

Comment: So does col mean column? Where you have "where col = @value" is col referring to column within SQL?

Comment: @Brit24 . . . "If I have a table with only one column, . . . "

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
DELETE FROM tblTable
WHERE fieldName = targetValue;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.