# How to exclude data in sql when a particular combination of columns determine its duplicativeness?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset which as far as I know is correct.  It looks as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX3c3.png)

```
    QuoteStatus Quoteid batchID EffDate Iteration   Months  Revenue
1   Block Ready 275576  900265  3/1/2019    1      1096     635791
2   Block Ready 275654  900265  3/1/2019    1      1096     635791
3   Sold        275654  900265  3/1/2019    2      1096     635791
```

However, I have a requirement that when a certain combination of columns put together, each record has to be unique.

From the resultset – I see this as a duplicate record because the combination of QuoteStatus = ‘Block Ready’ and Iteration = ‘1’ repeats more than once. (Even though QuoteID is distinct)
I do not want row 1 to appear and I cannot simply remove “QuoteID” from Select statement because I want it to display .

I have tried ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( PARTITION BY QuoteId Order by QuoteID ) as ROW_Partition. However the result is not what i am looking for. I cannot exlclude ROW_Partition = '1' because that would still leave row 2.

[image]

```
    QuoteStatus Quoteid batchID EffDate Iteration   ROW_Partition   Months  Revenue
1   Block Ready 275576  900265  3/1/2019    1           1           1096    635791
2   Block Ready 275576  900265  3/1/2019    1           2           1096    635791
3   Block Ready 275576  900265  3/1/2019    1           3           1096    635791
4   Block Ready 275576  900265  3/1/2019    1           4           1096    635791
5   Block Ready 275654  900265  3/1/2019    1           1           1096    635791
6   Block Ready 275654  900265  3/1/2019    1           2           1096    635791
7   Block Ready 275654  900265  3/1/2019    1           3           1096    635791
8   Block Ready 275654  900265  3/1/2019    1           4           1096    635791
9   Sold        275654  900265  3/1/2019    2           5           1096    635791
10  Sold        275654  900265  3/1/2019    2           6           1096    635791
11  Sold        275654  900265  3/1/2019    2           7           1096    635791
12  Sold        275654  900265  3/1/2019    2           8           1096    635791
```

I want to remove row 1 without explicitly excluding the QuoteID = ‘275576’ because this could happen to many other Quotes.

Comment: Please include the SQL and the data as formatted text in your Question, as that will help us be able to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Post sample data and the expected results as text (not images) and explain better the conditions you wan to apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to calculate the row number based on the columns you want to be distinct, keeping in mind that to filter on ROW_NUMBER you'll need to wrap it in a subquery or CTE ([SQL Row_Number() function in Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause)):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuoteStatus, Iteration ORDER BY QuoteID) as seqnum
```

You can then filter on this value.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff silly question here...can i use the 'seqnum' to filter out results in the same query?  Thanks.

Comment: @i.am.satishv . . . You need a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I will close this post now. Looks like using ROW_NUMBER() is the way to go however I could not get to exclude the 4 records which have Quote  Status = 'Block Ready' and QuoteID =  '275576' without using Quoteid as filter.