# function that allows grouping of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.  I have a similar looking output from a query shown below. I want to eliminate someone from the query who has 2 contracts.

```
Select
Row_Number() over (partition by ID ORDER BY  ContractypeDescription DESC) as [Row_Number],
Name,
ContractDescription,
Role

From table
```

Output

```
Row_Number   ID     Name     Contract Description   Role
    1       1234    Mike          FullTime          Admin
    2       1234    Mike          Temp              Manager
    1       5678    Dave          FullTime          Admin
    1       9785    Liz           FullTime          Admin
```

What I would like to see

```
 Row_Number   ID    Name     Contract Description   Role
    1       5678    Dave          FullTime          Admin
    1       9785    Liz           FullTime          Admin
```

Is there a function rather than Row_Number that allows you to group rows together so I can then use something like 'where Row_Number not like 1 and 2'?

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466963/sql-row-number-function-in-where-clause

Comment: Do you mean exactly 2 contracts, or 2 or more contracts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HAVING` as

```
SELECT ID,
       MAX(Name) Name,
       MAX(ContractDescription) ContractDescription,
       MAX(Role) Role
FROM t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=606586dd02130272f3c7177881f9fbfb)**

Comment: Thanks to everyone for answering, they all worked but decided to go with this answer because it slotted into my query easier

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * from (
Select
Count(*) over (partition by ID ) as [Row_Number],
Name,
ContractDescription,
Role
From table 
)t  where [Row_Number] = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this option-

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM table
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CTE` to get all the ids of people who got only one contract and then just join the result of the `CTE` with your table.

```
;with cte as (
        select
            id
            ,COUNT(id) as no
        from @tbl
        group by id
        having COUNT(id) = 1
    )
    select
        t.id
        ,t.name
        ,t.ContractDescription
        ,t.role
    from @tbl t
    inner join cte
        on t.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function rather than Row_Number that allows you to group
>   rows together so I can then use something like 'where Row_Number not
>   like 1 and 2'?

You can use a windowed `COUNT()`. The key is the [OVER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause.

```
;WITH WindowedCount AS
(
    SELECT
        T.*,
        WindowCount = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY T.ID)
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
)
DELETE W FROM
    WindowedCount AS W
WHERE
    W.WindowCount > 1
```

The `COUNT()` will count the amount of rows for each different `ID`, so if the same `ID` appears in 2 or more rows, those rows will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need `those record who have exactly one contract`.

Just extend your script, (My script is not tested)

```
;with CTE as
    (
    Select
    Row_Number() over (partition by ID ORDER BY  ContractypeDescription DESC) as [Row_Number],
    Name,
    ContractDescription,
    Role

    From table    
    )

    select * from CTE c where [Row_Number]=1
    and not exists(select 1 from CTE c1 where c.id=c1.id and c1.[Row_Number]>1 )
```